# docker-compose exit code 141

Tags: docker, docker-compose

One, and only one, of the nodes defined in a docker-compose.yml file fails to build. `docker-compose build` exits with return code 141.  The same configuration previously built without a problem.

The docker host log file, docker.log, reports an error:

```
level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/build returned error:
Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header):
```

Comment: If there is some permission issue, this can throw docker build & result it crazy error messages like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by the presence of a `.swp` file alongside the Dockerfile without sufficient permission for the current user to access.

For instance, this can be caused by having interrupted execution of docker build using sudo as a more privileged user.  In this case, removing the `.swp` file is sufficient, `sudo rm .swp`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with invalid characters in my image name (no .swp files, no concurrency).

Using upper case letters --> `error 141`.

Ex. replace: `image: my-app-ARM:1.0` with `image: my-app-arm:1.0`

Seems other had the same issue with invalid characters in branch names:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-compose-exit-code-141-on-shared-runners/9585/4

> I found that I was tagging the docker images automatically from branch
>   names and that some branches had invalid characters for tags and that
>   resulted in a exit code 141.

Answer (score 0):

No `.swp` in my case. A docker-machine restart did it.